# Install an OS on a hard-drive via VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu

Is it possible to install an OS on machine's hard-drive instead of virtual hard-drive using a VM (QEMU/VirtualBox)?

The reason I want to install an OS like this is because currently I don't have an opportunity to connect my machine to internet via Ethernet cable.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you asking if it's possible to mount a physical HDD volume to that of a VM instance?

Comment: Using a VM, I want to launch a live image of an OS and install that OS on my machine's hard-drive, not on a virtual hard-drive.

Comment: Have you tried to mount raw unallocated partition to the VM? There are tons of tutorial how to mount a physical partition to a VM.

Comment: I haven't , but I will.

Comment: The OS is also important.  Please add that tag.  Installing is one thing.  If it will boot when the drive is moved to real hardware is another.

Comment: I swear I've seen this same question here before, because I didn't think it was possible and a question someone asked here taught me it was. However, I cannot find it at the moment.